# wp_enqueue_script() not working

Tags: functions, javascript, wp-enqueue-script, scripts, buttons

I'm trying to add this social-network button:

```
<a href="http://svejo.net/submit/?url=[your url]"
     data-url="[your url]"
     data-type="compact"
     id="svejo-button">Add in Svejo</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://svejo.net/javascripts/svejo-button.js"></script>
```

to my blog posts.
But loading this in every post would really slow my page so I've try to implement it with **wp_enqueue_script()** inside my **functions.php**

```
function socialNetworks(){
    $opentag = '<ul class="socials">';
    $closetag = '</ul>';

    $socials['svejonet'] =
        '<a href="http://svejo.net/submit/?url=['.get_permalink().']" data-url="['.get_permalink().']" data-type="compact" id="svejo-button">Add in Svejo</a>'.
        wp_enqueue_script( 'none', 'http://svejo.net/javascripts/svejo-button.js', array(), false, true);

    echo $opentag;
    foreach ( $socials as $key=>$val ){
       echo '<li class="'.$key.'">'.$val.'</li>';
    }
    echo $closetag;   
}
```

However the script does not load.
Appreciate any help BR, Stephan

Answer (score 1):

The social network button you posted comes in two distinct parts.

First, the button itself is defined by the anchor tag.

```
<a href="http://svejo.net/submit/?url=[your url]"
     data-url="[your url]"
     data-type="compact"
     id="svejo-button">Add in Svejo</a>
```

Then, presumably the script replaced that button with an iframe or something similar so you don't have to send your users elsewhere to get it work work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://svejo.net/javascripts/svejo-button.js"></script>
```

The first part, the anchor tag, should go in your `single.php` file, and probably look something like this:

```
<a href="http://svejo.net/submit/?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>"
     data-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"
     data-type="compact"
     id="svejo-button">Add in Svejo</a>
```

That's not going to slow down your load time.  Next you can use `wp_enqueue_script` in your `functions.php` file.  Here we'll hook into `wp_enqueue_scripts` and enqueue our script inside our hooked function.

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse29581_print_scripts' );
function wpse29581_print_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script( 'svejo-wpse29581', 'http://svejo.net/javascripts/svejo-button.js', array(), NULL, true );
}
```

The last argument of `wp_enqueue_script` tells WordPress to load the script in the footer.  This will help keep the script from holding up the page load.

We can make this function a bit better, however, by checking to see if we're on a single post page and only enqueue the script if we are.  Only load scripts if they're needed.

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wpse29581_print_scripts' );
function wpse29581_print_scripts()
{
    // if this isn't a single post page, bail
    if( ! is_single() ) return;
    wp_enqueue_script( 'svejo-wpse29581', 'http://svejo.net/javascripts/svejo-button.js', array(), NULL, true );
}
```

That would be the proper way to use `wp_enqueue_script` in this case.  I think you're a bit confused as to how it works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't have single.php at all so I guess I have to fix that first and come back to your solution.
10x again appreciate your quick response.